# Add a button and action in a subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I have a class `CustomView` (subclass of `UIView` without xib file) in which I am creating some labels and buttons.I wanted to use this class in one of my another `UIViewController` to add those labels and buttons. I am able to add the labels and buttons to my viewController using custom view but if I add some action or event to the button(which is in custom view) , its not working. Please suggest me what should I do to add the action for the button.

```
//ViewController code

CustomView *slider=[[CustomView alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:slider];

//CustomView code


toggleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[toggleButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
toggleButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

// add drag listener
[toggleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];



// center and size
toggleButton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, width, frame.size.height);

toggleButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1];
[toggleButton.layer setBorderWidth:4.0];
[toggleButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
toggleButton.layer.cornerRadius=4.0;
[toggleButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.1 blue:0.4 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// add it, centered
[self addSubview:toggleButton];


  - (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
  {
   NSLog(@"inside drag");
  }
```

Comment: Is this related to hitTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with followings:

CustomView.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *toggleButton;

@end
```

CustomView.m :

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

@synthesize toggleButton;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
      if (self) {
            // Initialization code
            toggleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [toggleButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            toggleButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            // add drag listener
            [toggleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

            // center and size
            toggleButton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, width, frame.size.height);

           toggleButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1];
           [toggleButton.layer setBorderWidth:4.0];
           [toggleButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
           toggleButton.layer.cornerRadius=4.0;
           [toggleButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.1 blue:0.4 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

           // add it, centered
           [self addSubview:toggleButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
      NSLog(@"inside drag");
}
```

Add CustomView to the ViewController like:

```
CustomView *slider=[[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

I tested this code and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
[toggleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

with this

```
[toggleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the method wasDragged:withEvent? because in CustomView code, you set the button target to self, which is customview. So the button TouchDragInside event will be sent to customview not viewController. If you put wasDragged:withEvent in ViewController, it's not gonna work

Comment: yes,my code is in CustomView(subclass of UIView) only,but the control is not even going to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You added target as `self` for the action `wasDragged:withEvent`. For this to work(assuming `wasDragged:withEvent` is declared in you custom view), you have to rewrite the code to

```
[toggleButton addTarget:slider action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Comment: This code is inside CustomView only,I am creating this button in CustomView.So only I used self.

Comment: I have updated the code above,I have just added a method where I was planning to handle the UIControlEventTouchDragInside. Is there any other way to handle the event?

Comment: The same code works perfectly If i write every thing in my view controller, But right now my whole code is in subclass of UIView and here its the button action is not working

Comment: I'm trying to ask wether you want to handle the drag inside the toggle button or drag inside the custom view. And where in the UIView subclass(which method) are you adding the target and action?

Comment: I want to handle drag inside the toggle button and the target method added is -(void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event and I am adding it inside a setFrame method

Comment: lol. yes. i understood that the method you are adding is wasDragged:withEvent.. :D In which method of your custom view are you adding the line addTarget:action:forControlEvents:.. like maybe initWithFrame: or awakeFromNib ??